# Does a isolated point belong to $\bar{X}$?

Tags: real-analysis

I was trying to prove that $\bar{X}=X^{'} \cup X_{iso}$ where $\bar{X}$ is the set of all points which there is a sequence in $X$ converging to the such point (I don't know how to call it in english), $X_{iso}$ is the set of isolated points, $X^{'}$ are the cumulating points, I managed to prove $\bar{X} \subseteq X^{'} \cup X_{iso}$ so now I'm trying to prove that $X^{'} \cup X_{iso} \subseteq \bar{X}$ then I took an $x$ from $X'$ and I could prove that $x \in X^{'}$ implies to $x \in \bar{X}$ now I'd like to prove that $x \in X_{iso}$ implies to $x \in \bar{X}$ then $\bar{X}=X^{'} \cup X_{iso}$. But I couldn't go a little further from the definition:

If $x \in X_{iso}$ so there exists $\delta>0$ such that $(x-\delta,x+\delta)\cap X=\{ x \}$ it implies that $x \in X$ I'd define a sequence $(x_n)\rightarrow x$ where $x_n=x$ for all $n$ but it seems vert weird so I don't know if I got this right.

Comment: Yes, you got that right.

Comment: So would I have if any $x \in X $ so $x \in \bar{X}$ ?

Comment: I don't know what that means. Are you asking whether $x\in X\implies x\in\overline X$? Yes, sure.

Comment: yes, I misunderstand $\bar{X}$ definition, I don't need to have $x \in X$ to define $\bar{X}$ but $x \in \mathbb{R}$ then I think this is the motive which lead me think that something wrong would've had happened.

Answer (score 1):

Yes I'm right, let us to take $\phi:n\rightarrow x$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, clearly $\phi$ is well defined, and $\phi(n)=x_n \rightarrow x$